# SOOT like program analysis tool for Javascript

Tags: javascript, soot

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11313890/1299738) already but a graphical representation is not exactly what I want.

Is there a SOOT like tool for Javascript that gives you an intermediate representation you can play with? Or else, is there a Javascript -> Java-bytecode -> Javascript converter? (so that I can use SOOT with Java-bytecode to do my transformations and get it back as Javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such a tool exists. WALA can analyze JS to some extent but it cannot generate JS code again. Many people I know who analyze JS do this by modifying a JIT compiler.

Comment: [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) by Google comes close. They are using Rhino's intermediate representation and treating code rewrite as string composition.